# Proportional resizing of a scrollable list of images in css

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have an horizontal container taking all the width of the screen and a list of images in it that overflows it horizontally. I made the container "flexible" with an height in percentage and set a limit in px so that it doesn't grow past the real image height. I have also set the height of the images to be no more than 100% of the container's height.

My problem is the behaviour of the images when the window is shrinking.. 
When the size parameters in the html image tag are set, the image are not proportionnal, and when there are no parameters the image shrinks proportionally but there are some gaps between them and they don't keep there "left justification".

It seems simple enough but I haven't found what I'm doing wrong.
Also it needs to be pure css, no javascript.

[Example on JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kiguane/Qk7Qv/)

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <img width="100" height="150" src="http://placekitten.com/100/150" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/150" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 40%;
  max-height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
}
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
li {
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}
a {
  display: block;
  background-color: tomato;
}
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove property `display:block` of element `li`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/VAqv5/).

The HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/150"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/150"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/150"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/150"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#container {
    border: 10px solid black;
    font-size: 0.1px;
    height: 150px;
    min-width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: justify;
}
    #container div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 125px;
    display: inline-block;
    }
    #container:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%; /* Ensures there are at least 2 lines of text, so justification works */
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

**Scenario**

The issue is that the images can be of any width or height and also of n number of images may come. The solution is to make the container such that it accommodates images in such a way that their placement doesnt get distraction.

So from the above, you can see that when you shrink the browser, the images are not displayed in an awkward manner, but maintains its consistency across changes in the resolution keeping their position relatively consistent. Hope this helps.